# Multiple value insertion into mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I will use images to explain what i am trying to accomplish. I am trying to insert Values in a table  inputted in a box in any order.

Lets say the name of your website is **your Website.com**

The website lets you input values so that they can be summed up for data analysis like the image below.

[image]

Your **PHP** code looking like this:-

```
    <input  type="number"  name="Box1"></input>
    <input  type="number"  name="Box2"></input>
    <input  type="number"  name="Box3"></input>
    <input  type="number"  name="Box4"></input>
```

Lets further say that your MySQL table in your database looks something like the image below.

[image]

The names in the database are 1,2,3...8 as showed above.

Lets say for **Example** , the numbers 4,5,6,1 are inputted into the boxes on your site like the image below:

[image]

Let also assume that it does not matter how the numbers are entered.
The results should be like the image below in your database table

[image]

Lets add more numbers for **Example** 8,5,2,7 and it does not matter how they are inputted
[image]

After the numbers are added, your MySQL database table should look as follows

[image]

This is what i am trying to achieve. Having the table auto increment the entered values could also be nice but i figured it might be harder.

If the table could auto increment, the the MYSQL table will look something like the image below

[image]

I need help knowing how to achieve any of the end results. Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Sorry for the long story, i just wanted to explain what i wanted to do as basic as i could.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you got any table structure or PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a different database layout that allows for easier growth of allowed values, easier inserting and easier selection:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  number INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  amount INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

You can easily insert and update the amounts then using the MySQL specific [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO results (number)
VALUES (1), (3), (3), (7)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + 1;
```

Demo on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/382cd7/1

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but, I am still learning PHP; could you please break it down so i could understand your point.

Comment: @Adagoon This has nothing to do with PHP, it is only MySQL. What exactly don't you understand?